# Launch Android app from browser, when app doesn't have an intent filter defined

Tags: android, android-intent

I know how to open an app that has an intent filter defined, as answered in [Launch custom android application from android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser), but what if I'm not in control of the Android app, and it hasn't already defined an intent filter I can use?

Do I need to contact the developer and ask to add an intent filter, or is there some other way to open the application from a browser?

Answer (score 0):

If the app's `Activity` does not have an `IntentFilter` defined, by default the system will keep the `Activity` private and not export it for other apps to start it.  However, if the developer has set the `android:exported="true"` for that `Activity` in the app's manifest you should be able to start it by specifying just the component name in the `Intent`.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no android:exported="true" set. Anyway, this is for launching from another application, right? I need to launch from a web page in the browser.

Comment: If you are launching an `Activity` which is part of your app (which has the browser capability) then you can launch it by component name in the `Intent`.  No action, category or data needed.  But, if the app is a completely different package and the `Activity` has not been exported then you cannot launch it.

Comment: With browser I mean Chrome, Firefox or Android stock browser. Not a custom Android app with browser capability. What I'm trying to accomplish is to launch a third party app from a normal webpage.

Comment: Ok, then you'd definitely have to contact the app author.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks